# Displaying float values in python

Tags: python

Can anyone help with float values in python.
 I want to access values from CPP.From cpp I am getting value say 20.251. 
But in python its displaying as20.25099876 sometng like this.
 I want to display value as it is coming frm cpp.
 Thanks .

I have tried

```
i = c_ float
GetVal(Voltage, byref(i)) 
Print("Value is: " i.value)
```

Comment: read the tutorial [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: I have read that..tried also..but problem has not been solved yet..

Comment: the tutorial literally has  the code example `format(math.pi, '.2f')` that shows how to limit the number of  digits after the point.

Comment: thats what I am saying ..I dont want to limit the digits..I want to display as it is coming from cpp..Thanks in advance...

Comment: [you don't want the float to display as it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900392/displaying-float-values-in-python#comment53629607_32900435)  (seriously, read the tutorial). You could watch a [video about floating-point if you like](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0)

Comment: How are you sure you get it as **exactly** 20.251?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

`a = 20.25099876
result = format(a, '.3f')
print result`

Comment: thanks fr d help..but I want value to be displayed as it is..In your case it is a=20.25099876.
I want it as it is..No limitation for decimal points.

Comment: @Neha.m: if you read the tutorial then you should understand that `2.251` (if you type it in Python source) is represented as `20.251000000000001222133505507372319698333740234375` on the computer (with reasonable assumptions)

Comment: thanks fr d help sir..I know this has been printing like dis only..I am just asking is there any way to get values as it is..

Answer (score 1):

Decimals and floats are different in the sense that decimals have a base of ten (0-9) whereas float have a base of two (0,1). There are two approaches to rounding (not truncating the floating point, which just cuts the number off at the indicated decimal).

```
x = 20.25099876
s = format(x, '.2f')
print(s)
```

The .2 indicates the number of numbers post-float to print

rounding notation can be placed after a colon & inside braces of format strings

```
x = 20.25099876
'rounded : {:.2f}'.format(x)
```

Comment: Thanku so much fr d help..can it be possible to print without defining any limit..

Comment: Without defining parameters? (e.g. {.2f}) Keep in mind floats that are the product of mathematical functions are not always accurate due to their binary base so keeping a decimal long and unedited could warp the real value of the number. However, if you did not define any parameters you simply get the lengthy decimal you were trying to round. Additionally, in the second option, you can define a beginning and ending point to further mutate the float.

Answer (score 0):

One way to print the number without rounding is 
num=20.25099876
num = num - (num % 0.0001)
print num
It will print 20.2509

If you want to print the value as it is , like a=20.25099876 
Make it string. str(a) and print it.

Comment: In general, rounding a float won't work. Read about the representation error.

Answer (score 0):

Use "c_double" instead of "c_float" to get exact values from cpp.